# Changing variable in a function but it returns as the original value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am changing a variable within a function, but when it is returned to its original function, it reverts to the original. My code is

```
def myfunct1(v1, v2):
     v1 = v1 * v2
     print(v1)
     return v1

def myfunct0(v1, v2):
    myfunct1(v1, v2)
    print(v1)

v1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
v2 = int(input("Enter a second number: "))

myfunct0(v1,v2)
```

There are other functions in the code, but this is the part that is giving me trouble. How can I get the v1 value it returns to be the same as it is in myfunct1? I know that it does the calculation because it prints the correct number before the return v1 line. However, when it prints v1 from myfunct0, it gives the original number. Any way to fix this without adding more variables?

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the return value to your v1 variable.  Like this:

```
def myfunct1(v1, v2):
     v1 = v1 * v2
     print(v1)
     return v1

def myfunct0(v1, v2):
    v1 = myfunct1(v1, v2)    # <-- modified line ---
    print(v1)

v1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
v2 = int(input("Enter a second number: "))

myfunct0(v1,v2)
```

Calling a function does not change the variable.  Each function has its own context, so changing the value of a variable inside function is not automatically reflected outside said function.  Variables are not global.  Read up on variable scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to have the same value as in `myfunct1` many ways (one silly way is to just set both v1 and v2 to 1, therefore they never change)

I assume what you are really asking is, "how can I save and use value of v1 within `myfunct1`, within the broader function `myfunct0`?"

To do that, there are two options:

1. (The simplest way is to) just save it within `myfunct0`:

```
def myfunct0(v1, v2):
    v1 = myfunct1(v1, v2) # code will now print the same number twice
    print(v1)
```

2. (More convoluted way, if you want to use mutable things) is to define v1 as a mutable object (like a list), and then update that:

```
def myfunct1(v1, v2):
    v1[0] = v1[0] * v2
    print(v1[0])
    return v1[0]

def myfunct0(v1, v2):
    myfunct1(v1, v2)
    print(v1[0])



v1 = [1]
v2 = 2
myfunct0(v1,v2)
# 2
# 2
```